# Add horizontal error bars on a single point on a graph (R)

Tags: css, r

I have plotted a graph using

```
plot(data.exoplanets$loga, data.exoplanets$logMass, ylab="Log of Mass", xlab="Log of Semi Major Axis")
```

highlighted a single point using

```
points(data.exoplanets$loga[1535], data.exoplanets$logMass[1535], col="red", pch=19)
```

and used this to generate a vertical set of error bars, where KepError was the error.

```
lines(rep(data.exoplanets$loga[1535],2), c(data.exoplanets$loga[1535]-KepError, data.exoplanets$loga[1535]+KepError), col="red", type="o", pch="_")
```

How can I tweak this to give horizontal error bars for the x-axis?

Comment: `segments` or `arrows(...,angle=90)` ?

Comment: I was looking into arrows, but I'm not sure how to make them as precise as I need them to be?

Comment: what do you mean? `arrows(x0,y0,x1,y1)` specifies the starting and ending points: in fact `y0=y1` by default, so if you specify `arrows(x0=lower,x1=upper,y0=y,angle=90)` you should be done (then adjust `length` until you like the look of it; or use `segments` if you don't want "serifs" on your error bars

Comment: @BenFoxcroft: Are we done here or do you need further efforts?

Comment: @BondedDust sorry! I fell asleep, the arrows + segments work fine yes thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will produce x-axis error bars.

```
lines(c(data.exoplanets$loga[1535]-xerr,data.exoplanets$loga[1535]+xerr),
rep(data.exoplanets$logMass[1535],2), col="red", type="o", pch="|")
```